# Django Management Command does not import correctly

Tags: python, django, django-management-command

I am trying the execute a management command in Django that doesn't quite correctly import the modules.

My project structure is as follows:

```
myproject/
|-- appname/
|  |-- __init__.py
|  |-- management/
|  |   |-- commands/
|  |   |   |-- __init__.py
|  |   |   |-- somefile.py
|  |   |--__init__.py
|  |-- migrations/
|  |-- admin.py
|  |-- apps.py
|  |-- views.py
|  |-- models.py
|  |-- urls.py
|-- myproject/
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- settings.py
|   |-- urls.py
|   |-- wsgi.py
|-- manage.py
```

File `myapp/apps.py`:

```py
from django.apps import AppConfig

class MyAppConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'myapp'
```

File `myapp/__init__.py`

```py
default_app_config = 'myapp.apps.MyAppConfig'
```

File `myapp/management/commands/somefile.py`

```py
from django.core.management import BaseCommand
from django.utils.datetime_safe import datetime

from myproject.myapp.models import Car

class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = "Create initial data"
    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        cars = Car.objects.all()
        print(cars)
        self.stdout.write('Command successfully executed!')
```

The error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "myapp/management/commands/somefile.py", line 4, in <module>
  from myproject.myapp.models import Car ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'myproject'
```

How do I configure the app to have the management command address the correct dir?

Answer (score 0):

Normally (inside the command or inside any other app of the same project) I just import from `myapp`, not from `myproject`.

Have you tried this:

```
from myapp.models import Car
```

instead of

```
from myproject.myapp.models import Car
```

Comment: I did try that. The error still remains quite the same : "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'myapp' "

Comment: @Angy Just to be clear: are invoking the command the standard way? Like `python manage.py somefile`.

Comment: Yes! I did. .. Although, I figuered out the problem--it was none other than Pycharm that confused me so much. It highlighted the "incorrect" imports, which were not incorrect at all ! Thank you so much, though. It works :))